# How to declare a rails resource with a parameter for new action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a model named **Entree** for which the `new` action needs a parameter, the id of another model named **Cave**. I don't want to nest Entree in Cave since Cave is already nested.
What I did was declaring the resource Entree as follow in `routes.rb`:

```
resources :entrees, :except => [:new]
match "/entrees/new/:id", :to => "Entrees#new", :as => 'new_entree'
```

That works, but the problem is when there's an error in the `create` action, I want to display the page again with the invalid input. But since there's no `new` action, I must do a `redirect_to new_entree_path`, which does not keep the user input.

I have tried the following (simplest) route:

```
resources :entrees
```

But then the path `http://localhost:3000/entrees/new/32` returns an error:

`No route matches [GET] "/entrees/new/32"`

The question is, how can I declare the Entree resource in the routes file with a parameter for the `new` action ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Normally /new generates a form, which you enter the parameters into, and then create through the create action.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's a hack or not, but the following works and seems cleaner than 2-levels nesting.

```
resources :entrees, :except => [:new] do
  collection do
    get 'new/:id', :to => "entrees#new", :as => 'new'
  end
end
```

Now I can do a `render "new"` instead of a `redirect_to`.
I must say that I must have asked my question wrongly, my bad.

Comment: There is a slight disadvantage in this compared to the solution suggested by Vittorius: You will end up with a URL helper like new_things_path (plural) instead of new_thing_path (singular, sounds correct).

Comment: Check out [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34113174/1106878) as it outlines a less-hacky way of doing this with plain Rails.

Answer (score 17):

Rails has a [route helper](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-new-and-edit-segments) called `path_names` that does this:

```
resources :entrees, path_names: { new: 'new/:id' }
```

Comment: That is an awesome answer.

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

To improve gwik 's solution (which in fact didn't work for me):

```
resources :things, except: [:new] do
  new do
    get ':param', to: 'things#new', as: ''
  end
end
```

It gets you new_thing_* helpers (instead of new_things_*) for free.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Rail[s resource routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default), you will have to nested them according to how they work

```
resources :caves do
  resources :entrees
end
```

to get the route `/caves/70/entrees/new`

Otherwise, you are in a world of creating manual match routes.

```
match "/entrees/new/:id", :to => "entrees#new", :as => 'new_entrees'
```

I do not understand why you are forced to use a redirect? The new_entrees route is valid. You will not be able to use the [form_for helper](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for), since it is not a resource, but the [form_tag helper](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag) will work.

UPDATE: Render and Route

The Route does not directly change what view is [rendered](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) in the Controller. That is determined by the controller itself. Render examples:

- render :new will render the new action's view
- render 'entrees/new' will render the entrees/new template

Comment: Cave is already a nested resource, I don't want 2 levels of nesting. Also, the new_entree route path is indeed valid but since it's not an action I cannot use render. Or can I? I'm not on my dev machine right now but I'll try ASAP.

Comment: You can add resources :cave separately in addition to the nested version

Comment: +1 nest it.  Two levels if you need to. When you use rails you need to use the rails way or it becomes a hackfest.

Comment: You can still call render :new, the route does not change how render operates

Answer (score 0):

I found this generates the correct **new_thing_path** method not new_things_path as Antoine's solution.

```
resources :things, :except => [:new] do
  with_scope_level(:new) do
    get 'new/:param', :to => "things#new", :as => ''
  end
end
```