# rails, adding a parameter to new route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

The `new` action normally doesn't require parameters, since it creates a new resource from scratch. 
In my application whenever i create a certain type of resource say a `book` i need to provide a template, that is the id of another `book`. So my `new` route always has a parameter. 
I don't know how to represent this fact into `routes.rb` file.

Since i don't even know whether it is feasible, just in the case it isn't, then i will create a new_wp, a "new with parameter" action. 
I tried to add it to my

```
resources :books, :only => [:edit, :update, :show, :new] do

  member do
    get 'new_wp/:template_id', :action => 'new_wp'
  end

end
```

but rake routes say that it isn't quite what i want:

```
GET        /books/:id/new_wp/:template_id(.:format)   books#new_wp
```

that is, it has two params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
resource ...
  get "new/:template_id", :to => "Books#new_wp", :on => :collection
end

#  GET  /books/new/:template_id(.:format)  Books#new_wp
```

Comment: Ok, i've added a :as => :new since if not it doesn't generate the shortcut for the route. A problem still remains, that is: the shortcut generated this way is plural: new_books while it should generate a singular version :-(

Comment: You want it on collection, not on member.

Comment: You are right, like this it works, i just observe that the "new"s that it does automatically when you specify a resource and nothing more are singular.

Comment: To keep the singular "new", use the `path_names` option: `resources :books, path_names: { new: 'new/:template_id' }`.  From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34113174/1387338)

Answer (score 5):

I do this often, the easiest way, I believe is to just adjust the path_names. That way your route names don't get messed up. Let me explain.

**Scenario 1** - Standard Rails

Code

```
resources :books
```

Output

```
    books GET      /books(.:format)                         books#index
          POST     /books(.:format)                         books#create
 new_book GET      /books/new(.:format)                     books#new
edit_book GET      /books/:id/edit(.:format)                books#edit
     book GET      /books/:id(.:format)                     books#show
          PATCH    /books/:id(.:format)                     books#update
          PUT      /books/:id(.:format)                     books#update
          DELETE   /books/:id(.:format)                     books#destroy
```

**Scenario 2** - Chris Heald Version

Code

```
resources :books do
  get "new/:template_id", to: "books#new_wp", on: :collection
end

# You can also do, same result with clearer intention
# resources :books do
#  get ":template_id", to: "books#new_wp", on: :new
# end
```

Output

```
          GET      /books/new/:template_id(.:format)        books#new_wp        
    books GET      /books(.:format)                         books#index
          POST     /books(.:format)                         books#create
 new_book GET      /books/new(.:format)                     books#new
edit_book GET      /books/:id/edit(.:format)                books#edit
     book GET      /books/:id(.:format)                     books#show
          PATCH    /books/:id(.:format)                     books#update
          PUT      /books/:id(.:format)                     books#update
          DELETE   /books/:id(.:format)                     books#destroy
```

**Scenario 3** - My preferred and noted by steakchaser above

Code

```
resources :books, path_names: {new: 'new/:template_id' }
```

Output

```
    books GET      /books(.:format)                         books#index
          POST     /books(.:format)                         books#create
 new_book GET      /books/new/:template_id(.:format)        books#new
edit_book GET      /books/:id/edit(.:format)                books#edit
     book GET      /books/:id(.:format)                     books#show
          PATCH    /books/:id(.:format)                     books#update
          PUT      /books/:id(.:format)                     books#update
          DELETE   /books/:id(.:format)                     books#destroy
```

You will notice that in scenario 2 you are missing a path name, which means you would want to add an `as: :new` which would generate `new_new_book`. Fixing this you can change from `get ":template_id" ...` to `get path: ":template_id"...` which will generate `new_book`

My preference is scenario 3 if all you want to do is pass arguments for new. If you want to change the action then you would want to consider using scenario 2 but exclude `:new` from the resource or in your case don't add `:new` to the `only:` argument.

Comment: scenario 3 is the most elegant solution and should be the correct answer.

Comment: Note to other readers: Scenario 3 adds a parameter to the new action without changing the route helper, nor the action --- this might not be what you want. Yes, it is clean, but it can be misleading. When using a route helper, it would be handy to know whether a parameter is needed or not in the name itself. Otherwise, it could lead to maintenance bugs down the line, by a future developer. my two cents