# rails / resources routes / adding a custom parameter to edit path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, routes

This question is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794621/how-to-declare-a-rails-resource-with-a-parameter-for-new-action), but it hasn't helped me enough to get what I wanted

Starting with the model "event", I'd need to cut the form if different tabs, and for each tab, having a specific url, for example :

```
/event/:id/edit/:tab_name
```

If I add this route as a member :

```
resources :events do
  member do
    get "/:tab_name", :to => "events#edit", as: :tab
  end
end
```

The tab_name parameter remains dirty `/event/:id/edit?tab_name=mytab`
while using `tab_event_path(@event, :tab_name => "mytab")`

But Id like a clean route (or at least understand how)

I managed to do what I wanted with the following :

```
resources :events, :except => [:edit] do
    collection do
        get "/:id/edit(/:tab)", :to => "events#edit", :as => :edit
    end
end
```

but as far as I can get it, this route should remain a member

Assuming it might not be the right pattern to choose, but thanks in advance for any answer on this one

Comment: `member` means you'll get a route like `/events/:id/:tab_name`. Run `rake routes` to see what your routes look like.

Comment: And, edit being a default member; it can't be extended like this (/events/:id/edit/:tab_name) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
resources :events, :except => [:edit] do
  member do
    get "edit/:tab_name", to: "events#edit", as: 'edit_tab'
  end
end
```